# How can I join 4 tables with the condition that the data only exist in 2 of the 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 4 tables: t1,t2,t3,t4. I need to display t1.event_id, t1.event_name where t1.event_id only exist in 2 of 3 tables(t2,t3,t4). I try to use join but all I can do is return the event_ids which exist in all the tables.

Here is the DDL.sql.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 
(event_id       NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
event_name       VARCHAR2(80),
CONSTRAINT pk_event PRIMARY KEY (event_id));
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE t2 
(eid       NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
equipment      VARCHAR2(100),
CONSTRAINT fk_eid2 FOREIGN KEY (eid)
REFERENCES t1 (event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE t3
(eid        NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
security       VARCHAR2(100),
CONSTRAINT fk_eid3 FOREIGN KEY (eid)
REFERENCES t1 (event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE t4 
(eid       NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
setup_by      TIMESTAMP,
CONSTRAINT fk_eid4 FOREIGN KEY (eid)
REFERENCES t1 (event_id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Comment: Do you need exactly 2 of the 3 tables?  Or is the case where it exists in only t2, but not t3 or t4 also valid?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not have a copy of Oracle (or any DB for that matter) handy at the moment, but my first thought is to LEFT OUTER JOIN to each table and then filter down by decoding the existance of the id in each table?

```
SELECT t1.event_id, t1.event_name
  FROM t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.event_id = t2.eid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t1.event_id = t3.eid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t4 ON t1.event_id = t4.eid
 WHERE (
        DECODE(t2.eid, null, 0, 1) + 
        DECODE(t3.eid, null, 0, 1) + 
        DECODE(t4.eid, null, 0, 1)
       ) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need exactly 2 of the 3 tables, this query will not work without a bit more logic... but if you are looking for the case where one of the 3 relationships is missing, it will.  However, it should get you started for the exactly 2 of 3 case as well.

```
select t1.event_id, t1.event_name from t1 left outer join t2 on t1.event_id = t2.eid where t2.eid is null
union
select t1.event_id, t1.event_name from t1 left outer join t3 on t1.event_id = t3.eid where t3.eid is null
union
select t1.event_id, t1.event_name from t1 left outer join t4 on t1.event_id = t4.eid where t4.eid is null
```

Basically, the left outer join comparing the subtable's id to null will efficiently get you the rows that are missing from each table, and then you can union the results together.  If you want to ensure that the data is missing in exactly one table, you would need to do an inner join to the other two tables on each subquery to ensure that it works.  Something like:

```
select t1.event_id, t1.event_name from t1 left outer join t2 on t1.event_id = t2.eid 
inner join t3 on t1.event_id = t3.eid inner join t4 on t1.event_id = t4.eid 
where t2.eid is null
union
select t1.event_id, t1.event_name from t1 left outer join t3 on t1.event_id = t3.eid 
inner join t2 on t1.event_id = t2.eid inner join t4 on t1.event_id = t4.eid
where t3.eid is null
union
select t1.event_id, t1.event_name from t1 left outer join t4 on t1.event_id = t4.eid 
inner join t3 on t1.event_id = t3.eid inner join t2 on t1.event_id = t2.eid
where t4.eid is null
```